# get a line until | in iostream

Tags: c++, file, iostream

Currently I'm using the code below to read some variable from a text file like this:

> 12345|54321|TAN Ah Kow  |M|12 Jalan 3/45 KL  |Wilayah P|012-3456789|5000.00

The code is

```
getline(infile,id,'|');
getline(infile,pw,'|');
getline(infile,name,'|');
getline(infile,gender,'|');
getline(infile,address,'|');
getline(infile,state,'|');
getline(infile,phone,'|');
getline(infile,balance,'|');
```

is there any better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by better?

Comment: Primary-opinion based question and unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: Please clarify "better":  efficiency, readability, robust, portable, etc.?

Comment: You could factor the `getline(infile, dest, '|')` into a function, eg `next_field(infile, id); next_field(infile, pw);`. That saves you typing the `'|'` every time, and inside `next_field` you can test the state of the stream is still good to read from, and eg: throw an exception if it's not

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Boost tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/tokenizer/). They have a dedicated section which explains how to read tokens seperated by delimiters: [`char_separator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm).

> The char_separator class breaks a sequence of characters into tokens
>   based on character delimiters much in the same way that strtok() does
>   (but without all the evils of non-reentrancy and destruction of the
>   input sequence).
>
> The char_separator class is used in conjunction with the
>   token_iterator or tokenizer to perform tokenizing.

The below example from the documentation shows you how to read data delimited by `,`, `-` or `|`. You can easily adapt it to use your delimiters and input.

```
// char_sep_example_1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string str = ";;Hello|world||-foo--bar;yow;baz|";
  typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > 
    tokenizer;
  boost::char_separator<char> sep("-;|");
  tokenizer tokens(str, sep);
  for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens.begin();
       tok_iter != tokens.end(); ++tok_iter)
    std::cout << "<" << *tok_iter << "> ";
  std::cout << "\n";
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is: `<Hello> <world> <foo> <bar> <yow> <baz>`

Comment: Haha. I just missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you met..... [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html)?

The Boost Tokenizer class will make your life easier by tokenizing the string based on a specific set of delimiters. If your data is well defined<sup>1</sup>, you would know exactly what each token represents.

For example (C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int, char**)
{
    string text = "12345|54321|TAN Ah Kow |M|12 Jalan 3/45 KL |Wilayah P|012-3456789|5000.00";

    char_separator<char> sep("|");
    tokenizer<char_separator<char>> tokens(text, sep);
    for (const auto& t : tokens) {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Your data is well defined if:

1. You data maintains the same structure for considerable range of input.
2. You can define the structure well.